# Как найти количество путей в дереве с определенным весом?

Tags: алгоритм, дерево

Яндекс Контест. Задача G. Пути в дереве

Ссылка на задачу: https://contest.yandex.ru/contest/36783/problems/G

Т.к. для просмотра нужна регистрация, то для удобства напишу текст сюда

---

Дано укоренённое дерево на `n` вершинах и число `X`. В каждой вершине записано число — её вес

Назовём восходящим путь `ai, p(a_i), p(p(a_i)), ...`, где `p(a)` — родитель вершины `a`. Проще говоря, восходящий путь — это путь, который начинается с некоторой вершины и двигается в сторону корня (не обязательно доходя до него). Путь может состоять из одной вершины

Весом пути назовём суммарный вес вершин на этом пути.

Найдите количество восходящих путей с весом `X`

Ограничения:

- `1 ≤ n ≤ 2 * 10^5`
- `−10^9 ≤ X ≤ 10^9`
- `p_i` - номер родителя вершины: `0 ≤ p_i ≤ n − 1`, либо `−1` если это корень
- `w_i` - вес вершины: `−10^4 ≤ w_i ≤ 10^4`

---

Как решил я:

Начинаю идти с конца массива (дерева) и добавляю вес к сумме. Начинаю цикл, пока не дойду до корня и сумма не превосходит `X`, перехожу к родителю и повторяю предыдущее действие. После окончания цикла смотрю сумма в точности равна `X` или нет, если да, то увеличиваю счётчик на 1, иначе не делаю ничего. Перед переходом у следующей вершине обнуляю сумму

Код (интерактивный):

```js
class Vertex {
    constructor(weight, parent) {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}

function getNumberOfUpgoingPaths(tree, x) {
    let count = 0;
    let sum = 0;
    
    for (let i = tree.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        const vertex = tree[i];
        let parentIndex = vertex.parent;
        
        sum += vertex.weight;
        
        while(parentIndex !== -1 && sum < x) {
            const parentVertex = tree[parentIndex];
            
            sum += parentVertex.weight;
            
            parentIndex = parentVertex.parent;
        }
        
        if (sum === x) ++count;
        
        sum = 0;
    }
    
    return count;
}

// Обработка входных данных

const inputs = document.querySelector('#inputs');

const startAlgorithm = () => {
  console.clear();
  
  const tree = [];
  const [[countOfvertexes, x], ...vertexes] = inputs.value.split('\n').map(x => x.split(' ').map(Number));
  
  vertexes.forEach(vertex => tree.push(new Vertex(vertex[1], vertex[0])))
  
  console.log(getNumberOfUpgoingPaths(tree, x));
}

startAlgorithm();

inputs.addEventListener('input', startAlgorithm);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="inputs">6 3
-1 1
0 1
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 1</textarea>
```

Если хотите менять данные, то формат ввода таков:

- В первой строке первые 2 числа - это количество вершин и `X` (число вершин при обработке игнорируется, но писать его нужно, чтобы не ломать формат ввода данных)
- Начиная со второй строки перечисляются вершины, где левое число - это номер родителя, а правое число - это вес вершины

---

Проблема:

На каком-то из тестов (в яндексе не показывается на каком тесте) он ломается - возвращает неверный результат. На тестах, которые я сам придумывал, алгоритм работает верно. Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в рассуждениях или хотябы тест кейс, на котором всё ломается, дальше уже думаю смогу сам исправить ошибку

Comment: Было бы полезно добавить, какие именно тесты вы написали. Вероятно, что-то не учли (например пустое дерево, или из 1 вершины, итп). Т.к. одно дело это подсказать вам алгоритм решения, Второе - подсказать неучтенные тесты, Третье - исправить ошибки в вашем алгоритме и коде.

Comment: *"Яндекс Контест. Задача G. Пути в дереве."* - для названия вопроса это бесполезные сведения. Завтра эта задача будет на ЛитКоде, послезавтра в задачнике Гурина. Номер задачи - аналогично. Название задачи также не описательно.

Comment: @Kromster Не надо из заголовка убирать название задачи. Я их специально написал, чтобы следующий, кто захочет нагуглить проблему, мог найти по названию задачи. Для тест кейсов я добавил интерактивный код, где можно написать любой тест кейс. Я просто тестировал очень много тест кейсов включая то что вы указали (дерево пустым не может быть) и не вижу смысла писать их сюда - получится слишком много

Comment: "для названия вопроса это бесполезные сведения" - я много раз находил именно так решение конкретной задачи. Потому не считаю это бесползеным

Comment: Такой заголовок гораздо лучше, чем "как решить задачу". Однако в заголовке, в общем-то, достаточно последнего предложения, т.к. информация об источнике и в теле вопроса будет искаться.

Comment: @MBo А, я думал только по заголовкам идёт поиск. Перенесу в тело тогда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы упустили, что вес вершины может быть отрицательным

```
w_i - вес вершины: −10^4 ≤ w_i ≤ 10^4
```

Поэтому `&& sum < x` может остановить рано.

А по эффективности - в последней теме вы должны были кой-чему научиться.

пример на Python для подъёма из одного листа

```
from collections import Counter
import random
#a = [1, 2 , -2, 2]
#a = [random.randint(-3,5) for _ in range(6)]
a = [-1, 0, 3, 3, -2, 2]
print(a)
X = 3
res = 0

#следующие две строки должны выполняться при старте из каждого листа
cnt = Counter({0:1})
summ = 0
print(summ, end = ' ')

for v in a:
    summ += v
    print(summ, end = ' ')
    res += cnt[summ - X]
    cnt[summ] += 1
    #здесь пометить узел, чтобы больше с него не стартовать

print()
print(res)

[-1, 0, 3, 3, -2, 2]  #последовательность значений
0 -1 -1 2 5 3 5       #накопленные суммы 
5                     #результат - 5 путей
```

Comment: Нет, я учёл, что они отрицательные могут быть, по крайней мере по моим тестам с отрицательными числами всё работало корректно. Если веса отрицательные, то сумма будет уменьшаться, значит условие `sum < x` тем более будет выполняться, а значит он не остановится из-за него

Comment: Сумма 3, путь 1 4 -2

Comment: А, я по любому должен идти до корня, всё понял. Спасибо!

Comment: А по поводу эффективности: Эту задачу, тоже можно за линейное время решить?

Comment: За линейное время для каждого пути от листа. Что в целом получится, я затрудняюсь сказать. И помечать пройденные внутренние узлы, чтобы с них не стартовать

Comment: как решать-то? Намекните. У меня либо по времени либо по памяти не проходит. сам алгоритм вроде рабочий, но в чем хитрость сделать его оптимальным - не понимаю

Comment: @Serov Danil Храните веса путей к вершинам в мапе, значение-  счётчик таких весов. Для каждой вершины с весом V  проверяйте, есть ли в мапе вес V-X

Comment: @MBo
А чем это будет отличаться от обычного подсчета весов? Мы все равно проходим снизу вверх по всем путям. Единственная оптимизация, приходящая в голову - идти от корня вниз, тогда мы не пересчитываем корневые пути по несколько раз, но если делать это в тупую через структуру дерева - не проходит тест по расходу памяти

Comment: @Serov Danil  Путей всего не боле 10^5, причём пройденные вершины мы помечаем, и новые подъёмы с них не начинаем. Для вырожденного дерева пройдём один путь длиной n. Для полного бинарного дерева пройдём n/2 путей длиной logn. Остальные расклады, как я понимаю - промежуточные. Таким образом, O(nlogn) по времени и O(n) по памяти

Comment: @MBo  я не понимаю в этой схеме выигрыш. Мы в любом случае перебираем все пути, а значит начинаем с каждой вершины и идем вверх до корня. То, что мы их пометили - нам ничего не дает. Мы и так начинаем с них только один раз. Кэширование весов тоже ничего не дает. Ну либо я что-то не понимаю. Если мы например прошли один подпуть, он нам ничего не даст, если стартовать с точки ниже. Все равно придется пересчитывать с нижней точки и до конца. А ну хотя надо подумать. Если есть полный расклад сумм весов выше в мапе, то может это сработает. Подумаю.

Comment: Да, но проблема этот полный расклад получить. Нам в любом случае придется либо перестраивать мапу либо идти до конечной точки чтобы ее заполнить. Короче говоря, это решение неочевидно, в том числе по быстродействию

Comment: @Serov Danil Начав с листа, обнуляем Counter (В Python есть специальная разновидность словаря, по сути это мап с целочисленным ключом) и Summ, заносим `Counter[0]=1`  и идём вверх до корня. На каждом узле со значением V добавляем к результату `res+=Counter[V-X]`, потом `Summ+=V` и `Counter[Summ]+=1`, помечаем узел. В общем-то всё.

Comment: Поправлю последовательноcть: Начав с листа, обнуляем Counter (В Python есть специальная разновидность словаря, по сути это мап с целочисленным ключом) и Summ, заносим Counter[0]=1 и идём вверх до корня. На каждом узле со значением V добавляем его к сумме Summ+=V, результат модифицируем res+=Counter[V-X], потом Counter[Summ]+=1, помечаем узел.

Answer (score 2):

короче решенная задача на с++, основанная на вот этом тексте:
https://www.techiedelight.com/ru/count-paths-with-given-sum-binary-tree/
Но по-моему там ошибка, потому что там сначала прибавляется map[sum_so_far] += 1; и только потом считается long count = map[sum_so_far - k]; у меня этот алгоритм работал некорректно. Этот прошел тест

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

struct Vertex
{
  long weight;
  long parent;

  Vertex(long w1, long p1)
  {
    weight = w1;
    parent = p1;
  }
};

vector<vector<long>> createReverseTree(const vector<Vertex>& treeOrig) {
  long n = treeOrig.size();
  vector<vector<long>> reverseTree(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int parent = treeOrig[i].parent;

    if (parent < 0)
    {
      continue;
    }
    reverseTree[parent].push_back(i);
  }

  return reverseTree;
}


// Функция для рекурсивного обхода дерева от корня до листьев
long traverseTree(
  const vector<vector<long>>& reverseTree,
  vector<Vertex>& treeOrig,
  long node,
  long k,
  long sum_so_far,
  std::unordered_map<long, long>& map
) 
{
  Vertex& curVertex = treeOrig[node];
  sum_so_far += curVertex.weight;
  

  // получаем количество путей с суммой `k`, которые заканчиваются текущим узлом
  long count = map[sum_so_far - k];
  map[sum_so_far] += 1;

  for (long child : reverseTree[node]) 
  {
    count += traverseTree(reverseTree, treeOrig, child, k, sum_so_far, map);
  }

  map[sum_so_far] -= 1;

  return count;
}

int root = 0;

vector<Vertex> readTree(long n) 
{
  vector<Vertex> tree;

  for (long i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    long parent, weight;
    cin >> parent >> weight;
    Vertex v(weight, parent);

    if (parent < 0)
    {
      root = i;
    }
    tree.push_back(v);
  }
  return tree;
}

long getNumberOfUpgoingPaths(vector<Vertex>& treeOrig, long x)
{
  long resVal = 0;

  auto tree = createReverseTree(treeOrig);

  unordered_map<long, long> map;
  map[0] = 1;

  resVal = traverseTree(tree, treeOrig, root, x, 0, map);

  return resVal;
}



int main() {
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  long x;
  cin >> x;
  vector<Vertex> tree = readTree(n);
  cout << getNumberOfUpgoingPaths(tree, x);
}
```